# SQlite query - How do I retrieve multiple column data?

Tags: c++, xcode, sqlite

I'm having great difficulty to find a working example on the net regarding getting multiple values from a SQlite DB using xcode and cocos2dx. Here is the sql query I have:

```
char sql_query[100];
sprintf(sql_query, "SELECT * FROM SQList WHERE ColumnD BETWEEN %d AND %d ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", MinColumnD, MaxColumnD);
```

The query it self seems to work, the main problem is how do I get the values that I collect from 'select *' into another int or char parameter so that I can use it?

Some example I found referred to using a callback to a struct or mentioned about using sqlite3_prepare_v2 and the step method.

I'm unable to find an example for either methods though, please help!

Comment: There is a tutorial mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363028/how-to-use-sqlite-in-xcode-storyboard).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using `sqlite3_exec`, you have to convert all values from strings, and you have to use the callback's `void *` pointer or some global variable to return data:

```
struct MyData {
    string A;
    int B, C;
};

int exec_callback(void *ptr, int argc, char *argv[], char *names[])
{
    vector<MyData> *list = reinterpret_cast<vector<MyData> *>(ptr);
    MyData d;
    d.A = argv[0] ? argv[0] : "";
    d.B = atoi(argv[1]);
    d.C = atoi(argv[2]);
    list->push_back(d);
    return 0;
}

void query_with_exec()
{
    vector<MyData> list;

    char *errmsg = NULL;
    sqlite3_exec(db, "SELECT a, b, c FROM SQList /* WHERE ... */",
                 exec_callback, &list, &errmsg);
    if (errmsg) {
        printf("error: %s!\n", errmsg);
        return;
    }

    // use list ...
}
```

When using `sqlite3_prepare*`, you have to call `sqlite3_step` in a loop until it does not return `SQLITE_ROW` anymore (when you expect only one record, you can call it only once):

```
void query_with_step()
{
    vector<MyData> list;
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

    int rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "SELECT a, b, c FROM SQList /* WHERE ... */",
                                -1, &stmt, NULL);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        printf("error: %s!\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        return;
    }

    for (;;) {
        rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
        if (rc == SQLITE_DONE)
            break;
        if (rc != SQLITE_ROW) {
            printf("error: %s!\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
            break;
        }

        MyData d;
        const char *text = (const char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0);
        d.A = text ? text : "";
        d.B = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 1);
        d.C = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 2);
        list.push_back(d);
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

    // use list ...    
}
```

Comment: I think this direction is more as to what I need as I am using cocos2dx which is in C++. 

I'm still facing problem though... in the sqlite3_exec method, I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the callback's list->push_back(d); section.

When I use the prepare_v2 method, I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the  int rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "SELECT a, b, c FROM SQList /* WHERE..)

I'm assuming it's to do with how I declare it, but a bit stuck here.

Comment: Works for me. Write a *minimal* program that just opens the DB and calls `sqlite3_prepare_v2`; does it crash too?

Comment: Great! Thank you for the advice I figured out the problem now!
It was as simple as not allocating enough memory for the char sql_quer!

Answer (score -1):

Get the values using "SELECT" query and store your char and int values in an array.Create a NSMUtableArray and store the values which you will get from SELECT query .The following code will help you

```
-(int)find_putts_count:(int)holeno{
  sqlite3 *database;
 NSString *databasePath;
 NSMUtableArray *arr_tracking_details = [[NSMUtableArray alloc] init];
 int putts = -1;
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"GolfElite.sqlite"];
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
    NSString *sqlStatement = nil;
            sqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select Putts from Holes WHERE HoleNo == %d and ShotNo == %d and PlayerId == '%@'",holeno,1,[arr_players_id objectAtIndex:scorecard_player_no]];
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sqlStatement UTF8String], -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)   
        {
            [arr_tracking_details addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)]];
             [arr_tracking_details addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,6)]];
            [arr_tracking_details addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 4)]];

            putts = (int)sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 0);
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
}
sqlite3_close(database);
return putts;
}
```

Comment: This is not C++